# VariantTools installation error

Tags: r

I am receiving an error when using `biocLite()` for R version 3.1.0.  I looked at another post and tried to use `wge`t, but still get the same error.

Warning messages:

```
1: package ‘VariantTools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I need help installing this VariantTools package on any version of R

Comment: source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"):
biocLite("VariantTools"),
Works just fine for me

Comment: The [landing page](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantTools.html) shows that it is only available in 'source' form, i.e., on Linux platforms.